# MySQL Rails REGEXP cannot use backslash

Tags: mysql, ruby-on-rails, regex, activerecord

I am trying to do a `Model.where('value REGEXP ?', '\d+')` (i.e. 1 or more digits). But I cannot get the backslash through. In the rails console:

`'\\d+'` gives this SQL query `REGEXP '\\d+'` NOT THE DESIRED RESULT

`"\\d+"` gives this SQL query `REGEXP '\\d+'` NOT THE DESIRED RESULT

`'\d+'` gives this SQL query `REGEXP '\\d+'` NOT THE DESIRED RESULT

`"\d+"` gives this SQL query `REGEXP 'd+'` NOT THE DESIRED RESULT'

It either escapes the backslash or drops it but I can never get just one backslash to go into the SQL to have a proper regex search

Comment: Use `[0-9]+` or `[[:digit:]]+`, `\d` is not supported in MySQL.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `[0-9]+` or `[[:digit:]]+` instead of `\d` that is not supported by [MySQL REGEXP syntax](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/regexp.html).